# Unique Constraints On A Multi Master Database Cluster (Particularly Couch DB)

Tags: database-design, concurrency, nosql, couchdb, unique-constraint

Can you store unique usernames and passwords across a multi master database cluster using Couch DB? Some say it's not possible, others think it is. I tend to side with the latter. Want to get some ideas and opinions from practitioners with some experience in the field.

Thanks. :)

Comment: No matter your database tech with multimaster, there will be the possibility of conflicts.  It's a hot mess.  If you have a low-write dataset, this isn't an issue.  For instance, consider facebook: users need to be unique, so you could use something more like a single master.  for their posts. single master would never work, too much traffic, so high latency multimaster would work, with something like UUID as the PK, no issues.  That's at least how I see it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been thinking about a scheme which relies on Couch db's default conflict resolution algorithm. When a concurrent write is made against a specific document ID, Couch holds one of those revisions as the 'default' revision. What I effectively do, is delete every other revision unless a certain condition is met. Where I have document revisions that should replace the default, I just overwrite the document. It's a scheme that seems to work, but I wonder how reliable it is. Hence the question.